# Asymptotic bound on the expected value with a bound on the tail probability

Tags: probability, inequality, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of positive random variables, I have a tail bound of the form
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n \geq \delta_n) \leq \gamma_n
$$
with $\delta_n \rightarrow 0$ and $\gamma_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. I need to find a bound on $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$. Intuitively, I would use the following identity
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_n) = \int^{\infty}_0 \mathbb{P}(X_n > x) dx,
$$
but I can't actually move forward. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from plugging in your tail bound into the integrand?

Comment: Nothing I think, but I don't see how this could help me.

Comment: If you can rewrite the bound as $P(X \ge x) \le g(x)$ then you'll have the bound $E(X) \le \int_0^\infty g(x) \, dx$. Whether this "if" is possible depends on whether you can appropriately manipulate the expressions for $\delta_n$ and $\gamma_n$.

Comment: Is the direction of the inequality flipped, or $\delta_n \to +\infty$?

Comment: @angryavian: I don't have expressions for $\delta_n$ and $\gamma_n$ so I can't proceed  in this way.

Comment: @BGM: I checked, the direction of the inequality is correct and $\delta_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @user971821 How does $\delta_n\rightarrow 0,\gamma_n\rightarrow 0$ make sense for your tail bound? Your tail bound would then suggest a very small probability that $X$ is greater than some very small number. But this probability should be tending to 1 if $X$ is a positive RV, isn't it?

Comment: If $\delta_n$ is a decreasing sequence, then $\mathbb P(X \geq \delta_n)$ is automatically **non**-decreasing, so it's not possible for it to tend to $0$.

Comment: There is definitely something incorrect in your problem as posed. Perhaps either: (1) you actually mean $\delta_n \to \infty$ (as suggested above, though you specifically confirmed this was not the case), or -- you maybe actually have a **sequence** of random variables with this behavior, rather than a single random variable? In either case, your assumptions aren't enough to guarantee much about the expected value.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I have a sequence of random variables. I just edit the question.